# Sencha Touch in Android 4.0

Tags: php, android, sencha-touch

Have any one tried sencha touch 2 in the ice cream sandwich (Android 4). is it works?

Comment: I tried a ST2 MVC app I am developing on an ICS tablet and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it works, but there are some issues. From [their blog](http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2/):

> Last week we asked for your help in raising awareness of a critical performance issue with Android 4/Ice Cream Sandwich. Thanks to your participation the bug report has been starred over 250 times and last week yielded a patch from the Android team that addresses the flashing that can happen before animations.
>
> While that’s great news, it’s only half the story so we’d like to ask for your help one more time. While the flashing is gone, we feel that Android 4 is still not performing as well as it should when it comes to animations so if you’re in favor of better animation performance on Android 4, we’d like to ask you to take a moment to click the star on this bug report to let the Android team know how much this matters to everyone building HTML5 applications.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the version 1.1 4days ago. It worked quite well.
I had a galaxy nexus for my tests.

So i suppose their new version 2 will work :)